# can't convert ternary conditional java operator into normal if else

Tags: java, conditional-operator

i have been struggling on converting a ternary conditional java operator into normal one the ternary conditional is :

```
dp[i][j] = (arr[i] <= j) ? (dp[i-1][j] || dp[i-1][j-arr[i]]) : dp[i - 1][j];
```

and my attempt was "

```
if (dp[i][j] = (arr[i] <= j){
(dp[i-1][j] || dp[i-1][j-arr[i]]); 
}else{
   dp[i - 1][j];
}
```

can anyone help how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply this:

```
if (arr[i] <= j)  {
    dp[i][j] = (dp[i-1][j] || dp[i-1][j-arr[i]]); 
} else {
    dp[i][j]= dp[i - 1][j];
}
```

`arr[i] <= j` is the `if` condition

if it is true  `(dp[i-1][j] || dp[i-1][j-arr[i]])` is assigned to `dp[i][j]`

else `dp[i - 1][j]` will be assigned to `dp[i][j]´